# Open url in another window after Ext.Msg.confirm

Tags: extjs, confirmation

```
        floTrackBtn: {
            tap:            
            function() {
                window.open('http://www.flotrack.org/'); //WORKS
                Ext.Msg.confirm("", "Are you sure you want to navigate to Flotrack?", 
                    function(answer){
                        if (answer == 'yes'){
                            window.open('http://www.flotrack.org/'); //DOES NOT WORK
                        }                           
                    });
            }
        }
```

The first window.open works but when inside the confirmation message box, it does not. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? Can you add log inside your function and see what exactly are you getting in answer?

Comment: Can you add log inside your function and see what exactly are you getting in `answer`? Does the function even get called?

Comment: Yes it does. It contains 'yes' when yes is pushed and 'no' when no is pushed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - try to disable 'popup blocking' in the Safari settings. See if it changes anything

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code inside Chrome. The code is *absolutely correct* and it works fine.

When you run this code for the first time, your chrome browser will block the pop-up window, hence you need to select "`Always allow pop-up from this page`".

When you select that option, you get your o/p.

```
 ...
 ...
 {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'CLick me',
    centered:true,
    listeners : {
         tap: function() {
            window.open('http://www.flotrack.org/'); //WORKS
            Ext.Msg.confirm("", "Are you sure you want to navigate to Flotrack?", 
                               function(answer){
                                     if (answer == 'yes'){
                                        window.open('http://www.flotrack.org/'); // THIS ALSO WORKS FINE !!
                                     }                           
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
 ...
 ...
```

Sample o/p :-

[image]

When I select the yes option, it opened a pop-up window with the given URL.

[image]

Comment: You are right, it does not work becuase of the pop-up blocker, but how do I get it to work on a mobile browser?